# Is there a conditional preg_replace in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some code like this, which replaces some shortcodes with a link:

```
$search = array(
    '#\{r\|([^|]+)\|([^}]+)\}#',
    '#\{t\|([^|]+)\|([^}]+)\}#',
    ...,
);

$replace = array(
    '<a href="/ref/$1">$2</a>',
    '<a href="/type/$1">$2</a>',
    ...,
);

$content = preg_replace( $search, $replace, $content );
```

I have lots more that are similar so I was wondering, is there some way to reduce this to one simple `preg_replace` with a conditional?

For example, use the regex `#\{([a-z])\|([^|]+)\|([^}]+)\}#` and replace the first match with something different (r=ref, t=type) based on its letter? (If it helps, the shortcodes are like `{r|url-slug|LinkTitle}`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This calls for [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) (or possibly just the `/e` eval modifier), which would allow you to put the mapping `t` = `type` and `r` = `ref` in the replacement logic:

```
= preg_replace_callback('#\{([rt])\|([^|]+)\|([^}]+)\}#', "cb_123", ...

function cb_123($m) {

    $map = array("t" => "type",  "r" => "ref");
    $what = $map[  $m[1]  ];

    return "<a href=\"/$what/$m[2]\">$m[3]</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER:** What follows below is terrible advice, and suggests the use of a PHP feature that is quite rightly now deprecated. I'm only leaving it here for a historical reference.

Use the technique suggested in the accepted answer.

---

The alternative to the (perfectly valid) `preg_replace_callback()` method suggested by @mario is the `e` modifier, which is available only with `preg_replace()` and allows your replacement string to be evaluated as PHP code:

```
<?php

   $shortCodes = array (
     'r' => 'ref',
     't' => 'type'
   );

   $expr = '#\{([a-z])\|([^|]+)\|([^}]+)\}#e';
   $replace = '"<a href=\"/{$shortCodes[\'$1\']}/$2\">$3</a>"';
   $string = 'Some text as a ref {r|link1.php|link} and a type {r|link2.php|link}';

   echo preg_replace($expr, $replace, $string);
```

The only problem I can think of is if your `LinkTitle` contains a single quote it will be escaped and appear as `\'` in the output.

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dvEKNw)

**EDIT**

After a little trial and error, here is a version that works with anything you can throw at it, and also passes all the data through `urlencode()`/`htmlspecialchars()` where appropriate:

```
<?php

  $shortCodes = array (
    'r' => 'ref',
    't' => 'type'
  );

  $expr = array(
    '#\{([a-z])\|([^|]+)\|([^}]*"[^}]*)\}#e',
    '#\{([a-z])\|([^|]+)\|([^}]+)\}#e'
  );
  $replace = array(
    '"<a href=\"/{$shortCodes[\'$1\']}/".htmlspecialchars(urlencode(\'$2\'))."\">".htmlspecialchars(str_replace(\'\"\', \'"\', \'$3\'))."</a>"',
    '"<a href=\"/{$shortCodes[\'$1\']}/".htmlspecialchars(urlencode(\'$2\'))."\">".htmlspecialchars(\'$3\')."</a>"'
  );
  $string = 'Some text as a ref {r|link &1.php|link&\' with some bad characters in it} and a type {r|link2.php|link with some "quotes" in it}';

  echo preg_replace($expr, $replace, $string);
```

Outputs:

`Some text as a ref <a href="/ref/link+%261.php">link&amp;' with some bad characters in it</a> and a type <a href="/ref/link2.php">link with some &quot;quotes&quot; in it</a>`

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ecWvRp)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is here more to illustrate how to put a replacement string in the pattern itself using marker labels, than to purpose an alternative to @mario (aka the european squirrel) answer that is the way to go. But if anyone finds a case where this technique would be more appropriate, please let me know.

A marker `(*MARK)` is originaly used to confirm that the regex engine has reached a position in a path of a successfull pattern, but since it's possible to give it a label `(*MARK:label)` and since this label is returned in the result array of `preg_match_all`... Unfortunatelly, you can't access it in `preg_replace*` functions, that's why you have to match the whole string (even parts that aren't concerned by the replacement) and to join the different match results returned by `preg_match_all`.

PHP >= 7.4 (for the use of arrow functions):

```
$s = 'Other text1 {r|url-slug1|LinkTitle1}
Other text2 {t|url-slug2|LinkTitle2}
Other text3';

$pattern = '~
    (?<before> .*? )
    {
        (?: # you can fill this group with anything you want
              r (*MARK:ref)
          |   t (*MARK:type)
        )
        \Q|\E   (?<url_slug> [^|]+ )
        \Q|\E   (?<linkTitle> [^}]+ )
    }
  |
    (?<after> .+ )

~xs';

preg_match_all($pattern, $s, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$res = array_reduce($matches, fn($c, $i) =>
    $c . (
             $i['after'] ??
             $i['before'] . '<a href="/' . $i['MARK'] . '/'
           . $i['url_slug']. '">'
           . $i['linkTitle'] . '</a>'
         )
);

echo $res;
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/s8fqM)